# C++ Getting basic properties of a program

Tags: c++, c, properties

I am writing an algorithm that wants to check if google-chrome or has the same version as the input given by the user. for that I need a way to check what version google-chrome has. I am using a linux machine to program but I want to make it work at home where I use win 8.1

Is there a way to check in C/C++ what the version of a program is?
I thing it is best to get the awnser in a string because then i can just compare with

```
if(strcmp(version, input)=1)
```

Thanks for reading.

PS. I started in C++ but I can change, even to java if neccesary

here is the basic version of what i have now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
#define x 256;
int main(){
std::string version;
std::string input;
//get version
if(strcmp(version, input)=1){
    //versions are equal
    }
    //chrome needs to be updaded

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any answer will probably be OS-specific so you will probably need to specify your platform and OS.

Comment: On Linux `google-chrome --version` prints the Version of the browser.

Comment: @tgmath how do I use this function

Comment: What is "C/C++"? I mean, other than this amalgamation that you seem to be writing..

Comment: Why do you have that pointless #define? Why the ; after it? Why do you attempt C strcmp on C++ strings? Why = nit ==? Why is your indentation all messed up?

Comment: In simplest version: call `google-chrome --version`, pipe output to file and then write from this file. In more complex (and far more clean) add `tee` command to write output to pipe, and then write it in your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can launch a terminal process from C with the popen() command. You'll need to include the stdio.h header. Here's a code snippet that might help you:

```
FILE *pd = popen("google-chrome --version", "r");
char output[50];
fgets(output,50,pd);
pclose(pd);
```

In the output array you'll get something like "Google Chrome 25.0.1364.97"

Comment: yes, there's popen(or _popen) function in windows, though you need to change a bit the command. something like "c:\program files\google chrome\chrome.exe --version" should work, I think.